# How to disable prompt for running application in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I just installed an application in Windows Server 2008. When I run it, a dialog is displayed as warning to confirm it's running. Is there any way to disable the prompt?

Comment: mind posting a screenshot of the dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its called UAC (user account control). Its a "feature" added since Vista.

**A little background:**

Windows wasn't originally designed as a true multiuser operating system. Until Windows 95, it basically had no security at all. With each sucessive version, Microsoft tried to improve the security but they were limited in how far they could go and still keep backwards compatibility.

Most software developers got to used to the idea that the programs they wrote had unlimited access to the entire operating system. With Vista, Microsoft introduced UAC, which prompts the user anytime a program tries to access something that should really require administrative access. This is nothing new, other multiuser OSs have been doing this for years. In fact, most would require reentering your password every time you needed administrative access or even require you to login as a separate user with the necessary access rights. This isn't a big deal for other OSs because software developed for those systems only request administrative privledges if its really necessary.

With Windows, there are still a ton of programs that demand administrative privileges simply because it was convenient for the programmer to write it that way. Yes, you can turn UAC off. You can find instruction for doing so [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10,loband).aspx). But it isn't a good idea. As annoying as it is, UAC is one line of defense to protect the operating system from malicious programs intent on corrupting your computer.

Comment: not sure if I can change security permission to get around this issue?

Comment: I read wiki page on UAC at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control. This confirms that the prompt is Windows VISA's thing.

Comment: It's a server running a thousand dollar OS. I would question the decision to LOWER security to shave an extra second off your day.

Comment: Which is why I cautioned against it.

Comment: What security did Windows 95 provide? Windows NT 3.1 provided individual logins for multiple users in 1993.

Comment: I was referring to consumer OSes. Most security features were introduced in the NT line first and then migrated to the the consumer line as an after thought. At least until the two lines were merged with XP. By today's standards even XP can hardly be considered secure without significant "hardening" steps.

Comment: +1, nice OS background. However I still run into apps that are ACTIVELY being developed that insist on having admin rights b/c they have to update some obscure reg key or install under the C:\ folder and the user needs explicit access to that folder as a workaround.

Comment: @MDMoore313 True enough. If those developers were following Microsoft's recommended practices they would design applications to run with limited privledges by default and use a [shield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511445.aspx#shieldIcon) icon to identify features that require elevated privledges. When users click those features the app should start a separate process with elevated privledges, which would prompt the user with the UAC screen. Let's face it, it's easier (for the developer) to force a user to always run as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but it showed up during my search for the same thing. I found this article (http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/turn-off-user-account-control-uac-for-a-specific-application/), which points to a application that allows exactly that.

The above article describes an application called **UAC Trust Shortcut**. It runs as a service which can be configured using the tray icon (or from a shortcut in the start menu). You provide it with a Name and the location of the program you want run as administrator. Clicking "Add" creates a new shortcut to that location on your desktop which runs as Administrator without the UAC Dialog.

Installation is also very simple, just follow the prompts provided. The program can be found directly at http://www.itknowledge24.com/, who provide a 32 and 64 bit version.

Comment: This is effectively a link only answer. Please summarize the content of the link so that if it goes dark, the only source of information in your answer is not lost.

Comment: Attempted to provide as much information as I could about the actual solution the article was referring to. Any other tips to make this a more complete answer?